# How to write test class for LWC apex class

Tags: lightning-web-components

Apex Class

```
public class WorldEnergyServicesController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Location__c> getLocationwithKeys() {
    return [SELECT Id,Location_Name__c,Count_Keys__c,Notes__c FROM Location__c where Count_Keys__c>0 Order by CreatedDate DESC];
}
@AuraEnabled
public static ID createLocation(Location__c Location) {
    insert Location;
    return Location.id;
}
@AuraEnabled
public static ID createLocationKey(Add_Location_Key__c LocationKey) {
    insert LocationKey;
    return LocationKey.id;
}
```

}

TestClass

```
 @isTest
public class WorldEnergyServicesControllerTest{
    public static testMethod void TestMethod1()
    {
        Location__c Loc=new Location__c();
        Loc.Location_Name__c='Room 1';
        Loc.Notes__c='ABSCDSSSS';
        insert Loc;
    }
}
```

I wrote this but when i run this it is running succesfully but not showing any progress in percentage

Answer (score 1):

To test the Apex class, you need to call its methods in the testmethod

```
static void myTest() {

   Id result = WorldEnergyServicesController.createLocationKey(new Add_Location_Key__c(..) );
   System.assertEquals(Add_Location_Key__c.SObjectType,result.getSobjectType(),'should insert rec');

   ... then next static method ...

}
```

I strongly suggest you take the Trailhead on Apex testmethods.